# What is the Real Alter Rebbe Ksav?

Tags: history, chabad, aleph-bet-letters, mesorah-tradition, safrus

There is a tradition that the Alter Rebbe (R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi) innovated a new Ksav (*not* the one in the Shulchan Aruch Harav) and taught it to sofrim who passed it on from teacher to student.

There is an argument between [Rabbi Zilbershtrom](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=886&cat=11&haoro=3) and [Rabbi Zirkind](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=888&cat=11&haoro=2) regarding this tradition.

According to R' Zilbershtrom, the Lubavitcher Rebbe couldn't find a reliable tradition of this script, and didn't use it ([According to him](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=773&cat=11&haoro=2), both the Rebbe and the Previous Rebbe used Arizal teffilin). Therefore, he says that the "Alter Rebbe Ksav" that exists nowadays is not the real ksav.

We have a [Megilla](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15474&hilite=87d41755-981c-443a-9018-70567f2c4362&st=megilla&pgnum=56) of the Rebbe Maharash (the fourth Lubavitcher Rebbe).

Why can't we just compare our "Alter Rebbe Ksav" to that Megilla?

Comment: Every individual sofer - as is true with any other kind of writing - has his own slight variations on the basic letterforms. So the question would still remain which details of the Rebbe Maharash's kesav indeed reflect the Alter Rebbe's opinions vs. which represent his own style.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, to judge by the sample you linked to. For example, (most of) the alephs have their lower limb shaped like a yud, where the Arizal says that they should be more like an upside-down daled; the right side of the ches is a squared-off vav, where Arizal kesav would have it rounded; etc. I think it's pretty fair to say that the kesav in this megillah is Alter Rebbe-esque, but again, it's hard to know which of its features truly go back to him.

Comment: He seems to be saying that there's no mesorah ish mipi ish going back to the Alter Rebbe. But I don't really know (and indeed, in the second piece you linked, R. Zirkind disagrees).

Comment: How do you invent a new Ksav??

Comment: R' Landau (Bnei Brak) gives a hekshur on sofrim writting Alter Rebbe Ksav. While is it a topic of debate, where is the Rebbe in writting saying not to use A.R. Ksav?

Comment: @Alex Actually the arizal holds that parts of many Osios should look like a Vav for example the right leg of the ches, the left head of the reish or shin, etc. (the bais yosef holds they should look like a Zayin) and the alter Rebbe bridged between them, ROUNDING the backs of the vav/zayin to make a "P'sharah" between both opinions (I herd this from a sofer) so if the Rebbe Maharash Rounded the vavin/zaynin it probably IS the Alter Rebbe's Ksav...

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Zirkind was commissioned to write R"T for Rav Feinstein. The Rebbe was told by R'Feinstein that his were missing from the old country and couldn't find a qualified pair to replace them, nor a sofer. The Rebbe said that if he could get him a pair of kosher R"T's would he were them. And so Rabbi Zirkind wrote for R'Feinstein.

The mesora as per authentic Alter Rebbe's ktav is no longer a mystery with machloiket. Since the photocopies have been published we can now see clearly what it looks like.

My belief is that the kulmus, of Rabbi Reuvein, the Alter Rebbe's sofer, was upside down: his writing was from the outside of the kulmus, not the inside, as most sofrim do it.

-YM Goldstein, certified sofer - 770chosid@gmail.com

Comment: R (Moshe?) Feinstein couldn't find a qualified Sofer anywhere in America? Where did he buy Mezuzot? Where did he get his children's Tefillin?

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably talking about getting the same style/ksav as he used to have. This was probably 40's-50's so sofrim weren't as pervasive anyway.

Comment: The way I heard that story, the Rebbe convinced RMF to start wearing R"T because he (RMF) was a bona fide "מוחזק ומפורסם בחסידות" as required by the Sh"A for someone to wear R"T. RMF wanted them written in the script he was used to from the old country, so the Rebbe sent his sofer to write them according to the script described by RMF. If my recollection is correct, then the resulting artifacts would be based on RMF's tradition and not Chabad's.

Comment: @HodofHod Still surprising that there was no one in the whole lower east side who knew Russian? Litvish? style writing.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I think your answer will be better if you can cite to a particular authority from which you learned the story.  Also, its always good to edit your answer to take into account the comments.

Comment: @DoubleAA ...and was the requisite yiras shamayim and lamdan? Gedolim are famous for being scrupulous in their sofrim.

Comment: When the Rebbe asked R' Moshe ZTL to put on R"T's Tefillin, RM's response was that in Europe he used to put them on with a Tenay (that it should not be a vow), he lost both pairs of Tefillin during the war and when he came to USA he couldn't find a Sofer whom he considered a Yiras Shomyim so he only bought Rashi's Tefillin because he MUST put on Tefillin but as far as RT it wasn't a must and therefore he only wanted from a Yirei Shomayim.

Comment: The Rebbe asked him if I give you a Sofer who is a Yiras Shomayim will you get it from him? RM answered yes. The Rebbe's office called my father Shlita to go meet RM because he has special instructions concerning the writing. I will say that the accounts of the events as they are mentioned on some websites are mere fabrications.

Comment: @Meir Zirkind, I thought R' Moshe came to the US before the War.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not Medayek in connection with the when and why he didn't have them but he writes that it was very hard for him to take his Tefillin (and many Sefarim and letters) with him when he left Luban. When he came to USA he bought Rashi Tefillin even though he did not find Mehudarim. As far as RT's, he came accross an old pair which he put on for many years until they needed Genizah. See http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=14

Comment: And yes... Welcome to Mi Yodeya.

Comment: How does it compare to the Meggila? (also @MeirZirkind if you know)

Comment: The Rebbe Maharash's Megilah in the Sefer Hatoldos is not 100% clear to learn exact Deyukim, however, many years ago someone (who had one of the Megilos that the Rebbe Maharash wrote (he wrote one for each of his children)) showed my father the Megilah and he made 'real time' copies and my father uses that to study -and use- that Ketav. In all, it's written in the Alter Rebbe's Ketav as we know it with no major Chiddush.

Answer (score 0):

old ari zal is barely written anymore and that is what everyone had in Russia it could be that this what you are referring to.
The shaarei teshuvah o"h 32 1 says that one should not make his own safrus based on kabbalistic books because it is too deep for the regular mind "never the less one may copy the   (kabalistic) writing of famous sofrim and people of actions.
As for teffilin of rabeinu tam sh"a o"h 34 2 and 3 says that it is for someone that is yerai shamayim and someone that is famous for his chasidus puts them on at the same time 
Alter Rebbes ksav is a mixture of ksav beis yosef (ari zal) which are halachekli based and sfardi ksav which is more kabalistic. The ravs ksav combines the 2 together so one can be yotze both opinions.

Comment: One must always be careful when trying to fulfill two opinions that they don't end up fulfilling neither.

Comment: From the definitions I know Beis Yosef & Arizal are two seperate Ksavs

Comment: @DoubleAA - Are you implying that some types of kethav are pasul due to their forms? If so, can you please point me in the direction of some sources discussing this? Thanks. Kol tuv.